# python / pandas find number of years between two dates

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns that contain dates.  I want to know the number of years between the two dates while accounting for leap years.

The ideal solution would *not* assume that a year always has a certain number of days. Because years don't always have 365 days.

Sample data:

```
date_end    date_start
2010-02-09  1933-03-03
2010-03-19  1924-04-08
2010-04-19  1924-04-08
2010-09-06  1924-04-08
2010-09-24  1924-04-08
2010-01-09  1933-04-29
2010-02-26  1933-04-29
2010-01-31  1953-06-10
2010-07-07  1928-11-14
2010-12-01  1974-11-17
```

`date_start` and `date_end` are of the "datetime" dtype. I want a new column that is the number of years between the two dates.  It is simple to get the number of days between the two dates (`df['diff'] = df.date_end - df.date_start`) but then I run into trouble, since the number of years that passed for a given number of days depends on "when" the days happened, because of leap years.

This is analogous to a person's age.  I've tried adapting a number of solutions to similar questions, but many questions are about number of days or weeks between two dates.  I already have a way of getting the number of years without accounting for leap years, but I want to be more correct than that.

Comment: so from 1-Jan-2016 to 1-Jan-2017 is one year. What about from 28-Feb-2016 to 28-Feb-2017? From 29-Feb-2016 to 28-Feb-2017? From 29-Feb-2016 to 1-Mar-2017? From 1-Mar-2015 to 29-Feb-2016?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you want to define a year as 365 days, then you can do this:

```
>> df
    date_end date_start  is_leapyear
0 2016-02-28 2015-02-28            0
1 2017-02-28 2016-02-28            1
2 2018-02-28 2017-02-28            0

>> df['diff_in_days'] = df['date_end'] - df['date_start']
>> df['diff_in_years'] = df["diff_in_days"] / timedelta(days=365)
>> print df[["date_end", "date_start", "diff_in_years"]]

>> df
    date_end date_start  is_leapyear  diff_in_years
0 2016-02-28 2015-02-28            0        1.00000
1 2017-02-28 2016-02-28            1        1.00274
2 2018-02-28 2017-02-28            0        1.00000
```

As you can see, on years with extra days (Feb 29) , more time has elapsed between dates. In your case this would be:

```
    date_end date_start  diff_in_years
0 2010-02-09 1933-03-03      76.991781
1 2010-03-19 1924-04-08      86.002740
2 2010-04-19 1924-04-08      86.087671
3 2010-09-06 1924-04-08      86.471233
4 2010-09-24 1924-04-08      86.520548
5 2010-01-09 1933-04-29      76.750685
6 2010-02-26 1933-04-29      76.882192
7 2010-01-31 1953-06-10      56.682192
8 2010-07-07 1928-11-14      81.698630
9 2010-12-01 1974-11-17      36.063014
```

On the other hand, if you just want the difference in years. i.e. subtracting the year in which the dates happened (regarless of when in the year that date happened). Then you can do this:

```
df['date_end_year'] = df.date_end.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['date_start_year'] = df.date_start.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['diff_in_years'] = df['date_end_year'] - df['date_start_year']
print df[["date_end", "date_start", "diff_in_years"]]

    date_end date_start  diff_in_years
0 2016-02-28 2015-02-28              1
1 2017-02-28 2016-02-28              1
2 2018-02-28 2017-02-28              1
```

In your case this would be:

```
    date_end date_start  diff_in_years
0 2010-02-09 1933-03-03             77
1 2010-03-19 1924-04-08             86
2 2010-04-19 1924-04-08             86
3 2010-09-06 1924-04-08             86
4 2010-09-24 1924-04-08             86
5 2010-01-09 1933-04-29             77
6 2010-02-26 1933-04-29             77
7 2010-01-31 1953-06-10             57
8 2010-07-07 1928-11-14             82
9 2010-12-01 1974-11-17             36
```

Comment: Also what module is timedelta in?

Comment: from datetime import timedelta, and yes the is_leapyear is just for demonstrative purposes

Comment: well, technically there are aprox. 365.242... days in the solar year (time it take the earth to go around the sun). That's why we add a day every 4 years which would give us 365.25 now to get it to 365.242 we don't have a leap year every once in a while (something like every 400 years). So it depends on what you want :) [Tropical_year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year)

Comment: Is this not the answer you were looking for? Was there an issue?

Answer (score 2):

At first, I tried with praveen's answer, but found one thing not so intuitive:
If the start date belongs to a leap year and the end date does not, the result won't be an integer, although the month and day are same in both start and end date because the start date uses 366 and end date uses 365.

My Idea is to count the full years since the start date until before end date.
Then, count the days between 'no. of full years after start date' and divide it by 365 normally or 366 if either no. of full years after start date or end date belong to leap year.

```
def num_years(stdt: pd.Timestamp, endt: pd.Timestamp):
    stYr = stdt.year
    stMon = stdt.month
    stDay = stdt.day
    enYr = endt.year

    rv = 0

    # num of full years 
    calcStdt = pd.Timestamp(year=enYr, month=stMon, day=stDay)
    if calcStdt > endt:
        calcStdt = pd.Timestamp(year=enYr - 1, month=stMon, day=stDay)
        rv = enYr - 1 - stYr
    else:
        rv = enYr - stYr

    # remaining period less than a year
    if (calcStdt.is_leap_year==True) | (endt.is_leap_year==True):
        rv = rv + (endt-calcStdt).days/366
    else:  
        rv = rv + (endt-calcStdt).days/365
    return rv

# Test
print(num_years(pd.Timestamp(year=2000, month=1, day=10), pd.Timestamp(year=2004, month=1, day=10)))
print(num_years(pd.Timestamp(year=2000, month=5, day=10), pd.Timestamp(year=2004, month=5, day=10)))
print(num_years(pd.Timestamp(year=2001, month=1, day=10), pd.Timestamp(year=2004, month=1, day=10)))
print(num_years(pd.Timestamp(year=2001, month=5, day=10), pd.Timestamp(year=2004, month=5, day=10)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on Alexandr Sudakov's solution above is

```
df['Age'] = (df['date_end'].dt.year - df['date_start'].dt.year).astype(int)
df.loc[df['date_end'].dt.month < df['date_start'].dt.month, 'Age'] = df['Age'] - 1
df.loc[(df['date_end'].dt.month == df['date_start'].dt.month) & (df['date_end'].dt.day < df['date_start'].dt.day), 'Age'] = df['Age'] - 1
```

Which gives

```
    date_end date_start  Age
0 2010-02-09 1933-03-03   76
1 2010-03-19 1924-04-08   85
2 2010-04-19 1924-04-08   86
3 2010-09-06 1924-04-08   86
4 2010-09-24 1924-04-08   86
5 2010-01-09 1933-04-29   76
6 2010-02-26 1933-04-29   76
7 2010-01-31 1953-06-10   56
8 2010-07-07 1928-11-14   81
9 2010-12-01 1974-11-17   36
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to solve the exact same problem and created a num_years() function below to compute it.

The code breaks down the period between start_date and end_date into three periods:

1. From start_date to the end of that year,
2. Full years between start_date and end_date, and
3. From start of the year that contains end_date to the end_date.

It also takes care of cases where start_date and end_date fall in the same year, contiguous years, etc.

```
def num_days_in_year(date: pd.Timestamp):
    return 366 if date.is_leap_year else 365


def num_years(start_date: pd.Timestamp, end_date: pd.Timestamp) -> float:
    """
    Compute the number of years between two given dates, accounting
    for leap years.
    :param start_date: Start date as Pandas Timestamp
    :param end_date: End date as Pandas Timestamp
    :return: float representing the number of years
    """
    start_year = start_date.year
    end_year = end_date.year

    years = 0.0
    if start_year != end_year:
        send = start_date + pd.offsets.YearEnd()
        years += (send - start_date).days / num_days_in_year(start_date)
    if end_year > start_year + 1:
        years += end_year - start_year- 1

    if start_year == end_year:
        start = start_date
    else:
        start = end_date - pd.offsets.YearBegin()
    years += (end_date - start).days / num_days_in_year(end_date)
    return years
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a better idea for this case:

1. get years difference;
2. subtract 1 if (`start_month` < `end_month`) or (`start_month` == `end_month` and `start_day` < `end_day`).

2nd condition basically checks if the last full year has passed already or not.

It can be done using the pandas Series. One of the possible implementations:

```py
(
    df.end_date.dt.year - df.start_date.dt.year
    -
    (
        (df.end_date.dt.month < df.start_date.dt.month)
        |
        (
            (df.end_date.dt.month == df.start_date.dt.month)
            &
            (df.end_date.dt.day < df.start_date.dt.day)
        )
    ).astype(int)
)
```

Assuming that columns are converted into a datetime using `pd.to_datetime`.

Answer (score -2):

You could could convert your columns to years and get the number of years difference as simply as:

```
df.date_end.apply(lambda x: x.year) - df.date_start.apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

Comment: This is wrong, There is not 1 year between 20 December 2020 and 1 Jan 2021